# Theological determinism

Tags: ramakrishna, free-will

Jai Sri Ramakrsna!

How do we change our ways under theological determinism? If we are determined to carry out actions as part of our nature, how can we desire a change, even? If someone says to pray to God this requires a change already, for such a person has got the ball rolling, so to speak, in facilitating a change. For example, the idea of nama ruchi is that a taste or relishing of the holy name is developed, but this requires first wanting to make the change to having as such.

Jai Sri Mā!

Comment: For to actually go under change, a Guru or Diksha would be highly advised. Only a guided hand can walk on this difficult path and reach its goal, in my opinion.

Comment: Bhagavan has built the world in such a way that EVERYONE has 1 throbbing unremovable desire - to be happy/blissful/ananda. If you tie a cause (nama ruchi) with that effect (happiness), then they might follow that path. this is no different from advertisement where a good looking girl drinks soda, and you subconcsiously hope that drinking that soda will get you that girl. You advertise your path to Ananda, someone else will advertise their path. Viewers will pick one, try it, pick another try that, and eventually find one that always works.

Comment: As the Astavakra Samhita says "A man who says he is free, becomes free. A man who says he is bound, remains bound. This popular saying is true: 'As you think so you become.'"